# Maui Hybrid on Android - Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)

Tags: maui-blazor

```
I have an app in Maui Hybrid, when I deploy in Debug mode it works correctly, but when I deploy in Release mode, the application crashes and shows the message: "protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)"
```

I am using Visual Studio 17.3.4 on Windows and .net 6.0

```
Please help if anyone has the same problem, thanks
```

Comment: You can try clearing the program's cache. If it doesn't work, could you provide the relevant code for the crashing part and more error messages?